# How to implement Web Speech API in react native?

Tags: react-native, webspeech-api

Simple question. How can i use [Mozilla's Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API) in react native project? can i implement **webapp** or **window** interfaces in RN?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to build Android and iOS native modules that implement the Web Speech API using the underlying OS APIs. Native modules are fairly easy to build if you're comfortable in Java and Objective-C.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

It sounds like a nice open source project for the RN community.

Comment: thank you A. Goodale. but it would be challenging for me now, i will keep on searching :)